# How to develop Extjs component like date Picker?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm [ExtJs 6.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0) framework developer.

I want to develop a component like [`date`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date) that when user click it, It open a window and this window have some [textfields](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text) and other Extjs [components](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component). My problem is when I want to use this component as a grid cell editor. it does not show the component. In other words, I want to develop a custom picker.

**How do I do**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend [`Ext.form.field.Picker`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker) and implement `createPicker`:

> An abstract class for fields that have a single trigger which opens a
>   "picker" popup below the field, e.g. a combobox menu list or a date
>   picker. It provides a base implementation for toggling the picker's
>   visibility when the trigger is clicked, as well as keyboard navigation
>   and some basic events. Sizing and alignment of the picker can be
>   controlled via the matchFieldWidth and pickerAlign/pickerOffset config
>   properties respectively.
>
> You would not normally use this class directly, but instead use it as
>   the parent class for a specific picker field implementation.
>   Subclasses must implement the `createPicker` method to create a picker
>   component appropriate for the field.

It can look like:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.FooPicker', {

    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',

    xtype: 'foo-picker',

    createPicker: function(){

        return Ext.widget('container',{
            padding: 20,
            floating: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'box',
                    html: 'Foo'
                }
            ]
        })

    }

});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1139